# Query annotation with date difference

Tags: django

I would like to annotate a query with the following expression:
**(** [Due Date] **-** [Now] **) /** [Interval]

**[Due Date]** and **[Interval]** are fields from the database, while **[Now]** should be "equal" to **timezone.now()**.

So this would look like:

```
.annotate(ratio=(F('due_date')-timezone.now())/F('Interval'))
```

but this does not work as **timezone.now()** is simply converted to its **str** representation. What I need is to convert it to a date representation, in a way which is not database dependent. Is this feasible with Django ORM? Then I would hope that the minus and division operators will be understood with the date format.

Comment: What types are `due_date` and `Interval`?

Comment: What database are you using? What is version of Django?

Comment: Due date is a datetime and Interval is aduration expressed as a float. I'm using Django 1.9 and sqllite for dev, but will switch to mysql or postgresql for prod.

Comment: I've tested it on PostgreSQL and it works fine. It probably only occurs on SQLite backend.

Answer (score 1):

Use Julian dates and the database function `Now` instead of `timezone.now()`:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class JulianDay(Func):
    function = ''
    output_field = IntegerField()

    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        self.template = "CAST (to_char(%(expressions)s, 'J') AS INTEGER)"
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection)

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection):
        self.template = 'julianday(%(expressions)s)'
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection)


[...].annotate(ratio=(JulianDay(F('due_date'))-JulianDay(Now()))/F('Interval'))
```

If you need to use other database backends besides PostgreSQL and SQLite, see the [`Datediff`](https://github.com/michaeljtbrooks/mjtb-django-tools/blob/master/db_tools.py) function created by Michael Brooks.